# How to increase jvm memory available to Scala worksheet?

Tags: scala

How can the jvm memory available to Scala worksheet be increased ?

There does not seem to be an option available in the Eclipse preferences ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how recent is this feature, but it's certainly a possibility in Scala IDE 3.0.1. Just enter the appropriate value into the *VM arguments* field, e.g.:

[image: example]

Screenshot of full preference window from *Window->Preferences...* for reference:

[image: VM preferences]